# Why does CollectionUtils.subtract produce Casting warning?

Tags: java, generics, casting, compiler-warnings

I want to get the difference of 2 Lists of Strings.

I found [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) does that. However I am getting a compilation warning.

```
Collection<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<String> c = CollectionUtils.subtract(a, b);
```

Which produces:

> Type safety: The expression of type `Collection` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Collection<String>`

Is there any way to use this library and not get this warning? Apart from @SupressWarnings.

Comment: If you mean `org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.subtract(Collection, Collection)`, then that's because it returns the raw `Collection` type. This is easy enough to implement using `List.removeAll`

Comment: You've linked to the package `org.apache.commons.collections4` but you're probably **actually** using the package [`org.apache.commons.collections`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#subtract(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection)), which returns the raw type. The method you've linked to would not give that warning.

Comment: `Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<>(a); c.removeAll(b);`, and you don't need the 3rdparty class.